# How to use chunk Vue Js with bootsrap grid system?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is the code

I have **already read about others issue like this** but don't understand

*I am trying to add bootstrap row every **2** items*

```js
Vue.component('col-md-6', {
  props: ['data'],

  template: '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"> <label :for=" data.inid "> {{ data.label }}  </label><input type=""  :disabled="data.dsbl" class="form-control" :id=" data.inid " :placeholder=" data.label "> </div> </div>',

})
var inputgen = new Vue({
  el: "#container",
  data: {
    inputs: [{
        id: 0,
        type: '',
        inid: 'no',
        dsbl: true,
        label: 'Ariza №'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        type: '',
        inid: 'rw',
        status: "",
        label: 'Asosiy menu'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: '',
        inid: 'wer',
        status: "",
        label: 'Asosiy menu'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        type: '',
        inid: 'w4er',
        status: "",
        label: 'Asosiy menu'
      },
    ]



  },
  
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="container" >
  <col-md-6 v-for="item in inputs" v-bind:data="item" v-bind:key="item.id"></col-md-6>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you edit your snippet so that it can be run without throwing errors? Would help get an understanding at what you currently have.

Comment: Done, you can check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want it to generate a new `<div class="row">` every 2 items.
So that you can this (simplified) structure automatically.

```html
<row>
  <col></col>
  <col></col>
</row>
<row>
  <col></col>
  <col></col>
</row>
```

To do this, you can use a computed property that chunks up your original array, into an array with pairs. There are a lot of ways to chunk up the array, personally i just used the [first result from google](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/278/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks-of-the-same-size-easily-in-javascript), which worked.

After chunking up your array, you get something like this in return.

```js
[ [object, object], [object, object] ]
```

```js
Vue.component('col-md-6', {
  props: ['data'],

  template: '<div class="col-md-6"><div class="form-group"> <label :for=" data.inid "> {{ data.label }}  </label><input type=""  :disabled="data.dsbl" class="form-control" :id=" data.inid " :placeholder=" data.label "> </div> </div>',

})
var inputgen = new Vue({
  el: "#container",
  computed: {
    chunkedInputs() {
      return this.chunkArray(this.inputs, 2)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
      var index = 0;
      var arrayLength = myArray.length;
      var tempArray = [];

      for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
          myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
          tempArray.push(myChunk);
      }

      return tempArray;
    }
  },
  data: {
    inputs: [{
        id: 0,
        type: '',
        inid: 'no',
        dsbl: true,
        label: 'Ariza №'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        type: '',
        inid: 'rw',
        status: "",
        label: 'Asosiy menu'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        type: '',
        inid: 'wer',
        status: "",
        label: 'Asosiy menu'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        type: '',
        inid: 'w4er',
        status: "",
        label: 'Asosiy menu'
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="row" v-for="chunk in chunkedInputs">
    <col-md-6 v-for="item in chunk" v-bind:data="item" v-bind:key="item.id"></col-md-6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !  I just started using vue js and it's hard for me so far